# JAR doesn't include root files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have simple Java Application and trying to create JAR to distribute using eclipse.

[image: Project Structure]

But when I look inside JAR it doesn't contain the test.txt file. I created JAR as Export>Runnable JAR File

Comment: Put `test.txt` in the `src` directory...

Comment: instead of putting inside src what if I put all such files in resource folder?

Comment: You could do that, but you'd need to configure your project to include it when its built.

Comment: How to do? Any doc you can point so that I look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put that file into one of your source folders (such as `src`). Only those get copied into the jar file (by default).

Comment: Adding inside src folder does put test.txt in jar but when I tried to execute the program it gives me FileNotFoundException. I am referring file in Java code as coreService.printFileContent("test.txt");

Comment: @anjibman That's because it's no longer a `File`, but has become an embedded resource, which you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on your needs.  If you need to access the file as a `File`, then you can't include it within the Jar file. Take a look at [Location-Independent Access to Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) and [Retrieving Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

See the following image: 
Choose the file which you want to add in jar file.

[image]